# Can "one example of "be used with plural nouns?

Tags: singular-vs-plural

Can " one example of " be used to describe two examples as follows? In my language, these sentences sound natural.

> 1. Sushi and Tempura are **one example** of Japanese foods.
> 2. Sushi and Peking duck are **one example** of Japanese and Chinese foods, respectively.

Comment: Sushi and Tempura are two examples of Japanese foods. Sushi and Peking duck are one example each of Japanese and Chinese foods, respectively.

Comment: I think it would depend on the food, since for example when you say ‘fish and chips’ (at least in the U.K) you are referring to one meal, that being *fish and chips*.

Comment: No. You don't use singular verbs with plural objects in English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither is correct. In your first statement, you have two examples. In the second, you have two examples from two different groups. They should say:

- Sushi and Tempura **are examples** of Japanese **food**.
- Sushi and Peking **duck are examples** of Japanese and Chinese **foods**, respectively.

An exception to this would be if the *name of a dish* combined two items, for example, "*rice and peas is an example of Jamaican food*".

You'll notice that, in example 1, I have made 'food' singular. When speaking about a specific cuisine as a whole, we normally use the singular. However, in example 2, it is correct to use the plural because you are speaking about 2 different kinds of food.